# elseif statement in Standard ML?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Im doing a homework problem to make a function sumOdd to computer the sum of the first n odd integers, but i cant seem to find any sort of elseif type statement to do so. What im trying to do is below but of course doesnt work:

```
fun sumOdd n = if n=0 then 0 elseif (n mod 2)=0 then sumOdd(n-1) elseif n + sumOdd(n-1);
```

Comment: Nit: there are no statements in ML, everything is an expression.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg is `fun` not a statement? You cannot assign `fun` to a variable (see gist for example: https://gist.github.com/eatonphil/83252c39ef39c9f6886550e1ca711ca1).

Comment: @eatonphil, `fun` is neither, it's a declaration. When I said "everything" it was in the context of what could be a statement. Of course there are various other syntactic categories, like declarations, types, modules, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your function didn't compile because `elseif` is not a keyword in SML. Changing the last `elseif` to `else` and other `elseif` to `else if` should fix the error.

Furthermore, the function is more readable in the below format:

```
fun sumOdd n = if n = 0 then 0 
               else if n mod 2 = 0 then sumOdd(n-1) 
               else n + sumOdd(n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also remove the need for the else if expression by separating the base case from the general case:

```
fun sumOdd 0 = 0 
  | sumOdd n = if n mod 2 = 0 then sumOdd(n-1)
               else n + sumOdd(n-1)
```

You should also note that this solution does (and your own) does not actually sum the first N odd numbers. It computes the sum of all odd numbers less than N.

`sumOdd(5)` gives `9(5+3+1)` when it should give `25(1+3+5+7+9)`.